# Extracting multiple columns from a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix `M` of 15 columns, what is R syntax to extract a matrix `M1` consisting of 1,7,9,11,13 and 15 columns?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this: `M[,c(1,7,9,11,13,15)]`